# PHP should SplFileObject be used in all object orientated code

Tags: php

When writing to files in php, should the SplFileObject be used when coding in OOP style? and the normal file handles used for in procedural style.

Or, are each actually suited to different purposes as opposed to code style?

Answer (score 0):

Well SPLFileObject is rather less useful when working with binary files, so whether you're coding style is procedural or OOP it isn't much use to read an Excel workbook or an image file. For something like that, I'll stick to using PHP's standard file functions.

It is useful for working with text files of any kind, providing a lot of useful features to make files easily iterable (pity it doesn't handle prev as well as next) that are worth using whether your coding style is procedural or OOP.

So basically, use it when it is most appropriate and provides the features you need, not simply to suit your coding style.

Comment: I don't understand your comment about why `SplFileObject` isn't useful when working with binary files. The [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.fpassthru.php) shows that `SplFileObject` can open images. Am I missing something here?

Comment: My point is that it provides nothing to help work with binary files such as Excel files than the basic file handling functions

Answer (score 0):

All the SPL classes in PHP are meant to be offering additional functionalities or ease of use, over and above what the normal language function bindings provide. It is a personal choice if you want to strictly adhere to using that within an OOPs model or vice-versa.

In other words, I think (and this is my personal opinion) it is perfectly fine to write OOP code where I use array_* functions from PHP to work with my array instead of having to rely on Array_Object or iterators, if it suits my purpose at that time. Same applies for any other SPL classes too.